# Selenium xpath issue

Tags: javascript, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, selenium-chromedriver

I am having a very strange issue using selenium and xpath. I am having a page that renders 25 `<a>`'s with nested `<img/>` tags. I need to get using `findElements()` all this elements. If i get the page source and search trough the text the following substring: "alt="Expand List"" i get 25 appearances. But when i execute the command `let items = await driver.findElements(By.xpath("//a[//img[contains(@alt,'Expand List')]]"))` I get 32 items. I logged the items in google chrome and to the list are added `<a>`'s that contain images with different alt values. Any ideas? The piece of code:

```
    let text = await driver.getPageSource();
    var count = (text.match(/alt="Expand List"/g) || []).length;
    let items = await driver.findElements(By.xpath("//a[//img[contains(@alt,'Expand List')]]"))
    console.log(count, items.length); //outputs 25, 32
```

[image]
And this image with the alt `Collapse List` appears in a `<a>`

[image]

Comment: can you try with XPATH like  `//a//img[contains(@alt,'Expand List')]` ?

Comment: I think your xpath is incorrectly defining a predicate. I think(?) that it's finding any A that then returns true for your predicate (//img[contains(@alt,'Expand List')]) which is always true since it's using //. Try the example in the comment above, I think it's closer to what you're intending.

Answer (score 1):

Your xpath should be more like:

```
//a/img[contains(@alt,'Expand List')]
```

One slash indicates it's a child of the parent `//a`.

I highly recommend getting a brower addon to test xpaths. One that I use almost everyday is ChroPath. You can also test xpaths in the devtools console with something like

```
$x('//a/img[contains(@alt,'Expand List')]')
```

Will give output like this:

[image: XPath in Devtools console]